# How to get current cart items for logged in user

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

Following is my code:-

```
 try
        {
          $store = $this->_getStore();
          Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store->getId());
          $customer_ID = 3;
          $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_ID);

          // load quote by customer
          $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_ID);

          $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
          $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                     // set the current store ID
                     ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                     // load the product object
                     ->load(3);

           // Add Product to Quote
           $quote->addProduct($product,1);

           // Calculate the new Cart total and Save Quote
           $quote->collectTotals()->save();

           return json_encode(array("", $quote->getId()));

        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            return $e->getMessage();;
        }
```

Using this the product is getting added in cart successfully and returning quote_id, but using this id i want to fetch current cart items details for currently logged in user.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load quote collection and filter via id or you can try below code for your requirement:

```
// retrieve quote items array
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";          
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I want to load cart items for logged in user, will this code work?

Comment: This code is not working, please check above my code and provide me your answer based on it.

Comment: What happened sir?

Comment: Is it possible to get cart details using customer id